# Rails 3.1 and Javascript templates

Tags: javascript, templates, ruby-on-rails-3.1

What should i using in **rails 3.1** for support javascript template(how JST["path_to_template"]).

Answer (score 0):

You are free to pick any JS template engine you want.
Just add it to your [javascript assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

I prefer [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) for example.